# How to localize RCDATA resources with Translation Editor

Tags: delphi, localization, resource-dll

I am embedding some images and texts as RCDATA resources to my executable.
My project includes special `app.rc` file for this purpose:

```
Text1 RCDATA "text1.rtf"
Image1 RCDATA "Images\image1.png"
```

Later I am accessing these data using `TResourceStream`.

I want this `app.rc` file to be localized and included to resource dll.
I can't find a way to include different files as RCDATA resources for different languages. 
Main executable should include one set of files (`text1.rtf`,`Images\image1.png`) as resources, resource DLL should include another version of `text1.rtf`,`Images\image1.png`files.